# Attending supervisor's group meeting after thesis approval

Tags: advisor

I am a finishing Masters student. My supervisor approved my thesis recently, and I am waiting for the graduate studies office to process my thesis so that I can get a letter from the university that confirms the submission of my thesis and apply for a post-graduate work permit.

In the meantime, should I still attend my supervisor's group meeting? I do not contribute to the discussions in the group meetings anyway.

I cannot bring up the topic of attending group meeting because once before, when I asked him about the logistics of the final stages of the Masters program, he got really mad at me.

Comment: Why would he get mad at you for asking that? It does not make any sense...

Comment: May be because I study in a theoretical subject and I'm switching fields, and I do not need his reference letter afterwards, so I don't need to carefully balance my act with him every time. Who knows!!!!

Comment: Is this at a US school, or somewhere else?

Comment: it's in canada. i'd rather not go - i don't need to; i'm just being cordial. But i'm still wanting to know what the general populace thinks of this.

Comment: If you can't discuss something like this with your supervisor you should look for a new supervisor. If you have no intention of staying in this group, why should you attend its meetings after finishing your project?

Comment: @Roland A lot of people in the department do not know that I quit. I feel like it would be a bad name for him since i quit so soon (just after my masters). I go to the group meetings just to show my face and not have people question whatever happened to me and why i'm not coming even though the group meetings have not ended for this year.

Comment: People don't know that you have submitted your Masters thesis? That seems like something you'd mention at a group meeting. You seem to be in a strongly dysfunctional environment.

Comment: I don't even get why you'd think there's a problem skipping the meeting. You're done. Is this a MS/PhD program you are quitting early and still getting a stipend currently?

Comment: I am finishing now after the MS program. I have been funded by a fellowship throughout my MS program. If you are funded by a fellowship, the supervisor has to pay a top-up of 20% to you. My supervisor broke the top-up into monthly installments. I am still receiving the top-up as installments.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule: go if you think it would be useful to you, though it would probably be polite to check with the supervisor first:

> "Is it ok if I still come to lab meetings during my thesis-pending period [or whatever it is called in your location]? I'd be interested in keeping up with the work the group is doing."

Usually I would expect the supervisor would be glad to accommodate you. And even if you are not reporting on any work of your own, you might have useful input regarding other people's work.

In your particular situation - "he got really mad at me" - for whatever reason it does not sound as if you have a very healthy relationship with your supervisor. So it's probably in your best interests just to move on. It's hard to say how your supervisor might feel about that, but in this instance you are better off thinking of yourself rather than trying to maintain an unhealthy relationship.